# Getting the Raw Data Out of an Excel Pivot Table in Python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, pivot-table

I have a pivot table in excel that I want to read the raw data from that table into python. Is it possible to do this? I do not see anything in the documentation on it or on Stack Overflow.

If the community could be provided some examples on how to read the raw data that drives pivot tables, this could greatly assist in routine analytical tasks.

**EDIT:** 
In this scenario there are no raw data tabs. I want to know how to ping the pivot table get the raw data and read it into python.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong: doesn't your excel pivot table pull its data from a standard excel table? This table could be read using a standard `pd.read_excel()`?

Comment: @JimEisenberg it will only read what is immediately visible. So it will read what is displayed on the Pivot table, but not all of the raw data.

Comment: But what data is the pivot table built on? It it in another tab on the file?

Comment: @JimEisenberg it’s not in any tabs on the excel file that’s why I’m asking generally what is the best approach to ping the pivot table and get the raw data like I specified in my question.

Comment: found a solution?

Comment: @JonathanLam I did not

Answer (score 0):

First, recreate raw data from the pivot table. The pivot table has full information to rebuild the raw data.

1. Make sure that none of the items in the pivot table fields are hidden -- clear all the filters and Slicers that have been applied.
2. The pivot table does not need to contain all the fields -- just make sure that there is at least one field in the Values area.
3. Show the grand totals for rows and columns. If the totals aren't visible, select a cell in the pivot table, and on the Ribbon, under PivotTable Tools, click the Analyze tab. In the Layout group, click Grand totals, then click On for Rows and Columns.
4. Double-click the grand total cell at the bottom right of the pivot table. This should create a new sheet with the related records from the original source data.

Then, you could read the raw data from the source.

Comment: But how can I do it programmatically with python?